# Efficient feeding of data for reinforcement learning algorithms

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I am currently implementing the deep double Q learning algorithm in TensorFlow. I have an experience replay buffer implemented based on NumPy arrays. However, some performance analysis shows that the feeding of the data from NumPy arrays to the graph using feed_dict is very inefficient. This is also pointed out in the documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to have the feeding can be done more efficiently? With static datasets the feeding can be done with input pipelines, such as record readers. Experience replay buffer, however, change with time, making this type of feeding more challenging.

Any answers are greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **there is no way to speed it up** if your data is a minimum set and is unique.  If your data has some redundancies or unneeded decoration that you can remove, then remove it prior to feeding it into your model, but assuming you've already done that and your data is unique in each batch, then there is nothing (in this regard) that you can do.

That said, there are things you can do to improve your networks performance.

- Your Q-learning algorithm may be able to be improved as per [this paper](http://file:///Users/anton/Downloads/Wiering_98_fastonline.pdf), which basically says don't do a learning phase until your network as accumulated error past a threshold.
- If you are reusing some of the training sets or replaying them, then you could use a load stage to load the training data into the GPU for quick playback.